# How do you find an apartment/property for rent in a major Swedish city?

Tags: accommodation, sweden, relocation, rental

I've heard about Sweden having a very bad availability of rental places (waiting lists that can span years). I was wondering how to find an apartment or property for rent in Sweden as a foreigner hoping to move.

I realize it will be difficult (if not impossible) to find a rental BEFORE coming but afterward, what's the process and how do you do it?

As far as specific locations, I'm wondering about Stockholm, Malmö, or other large cities. If it's preferable to live out in the suburbs, please provide information on how to find an apartment there.

Comment: You may be able to find someone to swap your current home in with for an apartment here in Sweden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, some people seem to wait a very long time to get an apartment inside Stockholm but it's easier to find something a bit outside the prime areas.

Unless you can get something through an employer or personal contact, your best bet would probably be to use an online service like [bostad direkt](http://www.bostaddirekt.com). Click the UK flag to get the basics in English. There are several other sources such as [Bovision](http://bovision.se), [Hemnet](http://www.hemnet.se) and [AndraHand](http://www.andrahand.se). These don't seem to offer English search pages but the last one specializes in sublets (second-hand rentals).

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the two largest housingportals in sweden

- http://www.bostadsdeal.se
- http://www.bostadsfinder.se